# File transfer succeeds only  the first time, fails consuquently

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, file-transfer

This is a file transfer send/receive program using sockets TCP. This code is included in both client and server application and it works fine only for the first time.

The second time, the side which is going to receive gets 0 and the transfer finishes. How can I fix it so it can be used many times?

```
public static void sendFile(string filePath)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    byte[] fileData;
    try
    {
        //sending file name and file size to the server
        busy = true;
        fileSize = fs.Length;
        byte[] fileDetial = null;
        string detail =  fileName + "," + fileSize.ToString();
        fileDetial = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(detail);
        client.Send(fileDetial);

        //sending file data to the server

        fileData = new byte[packetSize];
        count = 0;
        sum = 0;
        Program.thFP.Start();                           // running transfer rate
        Program.fp.StatusLabel("Sending data...");
        transferRate.timeLeft();

        while (sum < fileSize)
        {
            fs.Seek(sum, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fs.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            count = client.Send(fileData, 0, fileData.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            sum += count;
            Program.fp.ProgressBarFileHandler(sum, fileSize);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        busy = false;
        fs.Close();
        fileData = null;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} sent successfully", fileName));
    }
}
```

there's no problem at all with the code below as i guess .. i think the problem is in the SENDFILE method .. but here's the receiveFile code .. it might help

```
public static void ReceiveFile()
{

    //receving file name and file size from server
    busy = true;
    byte[] commandData = new byte[1024];
    client.Receive(commandData);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(commandData));
    string[] Command = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(commandData).Split(',');
    string fileName = Command[0];
    fileSize = Convert.ToInt64(Command[1]);
    Program.thFP.Start();                           // running transfer rate
    Program.fp.StatusLabel("Receiving data...");
    transferRate.timeLeft();

    // receiving the file data from server
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\" + fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    byte[] fileData = new byte[packetSize];
    try
    {
        count = 0;
        sum = 0;
        while (sum < fileSize)
        {
            count = client.Receive(fileData,0,fileData.Length, SocketFlags.None);
            fs.Seek(sum, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            fs.Write(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
            sum += count;
            Program.fp.ProgressBarFileHandler(sum,fileSize);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        busy = false;
        fs.Close();
        fileData = null;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} recevied successfully", fileName));
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you remove the try...finally, or atleast add a catch statement, to see if an Exception is being thrown somewhere.

Comment: i removed the try and finally .. the application didn't stop or gave me an error.. i think something wrong gets with the socket after the first transfer :S

Comment: You can run `netstat` to see what state the port is in.

Comment: Run it from the command prompt:  `netstat /?` for the options.

Comment: @ChrisO the server is always active... and works fine.. after i send the file completely.. i can close the client and reopen it and reconnect to server again with out restarting the server application and i can send another file in that way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the code. The problem was in the `SendFile` method and exactly in the `FileStream`

I should **Dispose** it, so I can initialize it again with the new path

```
finally
{
    busy = false;
    fs.Dispose();   //here i fixed my mistake it was fs.Close()
    fileData = null;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} sent successfully", fileName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you need to dispose of the FileStream.  I' recommend wrapping it in a using block, so it will always be disposed even if an excpetion is thrown.

```
// receiving the file data from server
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\" + fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    byte[] fileData = new byte[packetSize];
    try
    {
        ...same code as before here...
    }
    finally
    {
         ...same code as before here...
    }
}
```

I always recommend wrapping streams in a using block.  It means that if you later come back and edit the code, there is less danger of you introducing a code path that does not dispose of the stream when done.

I'd also restructure the code so that your "Successful" message isn't in a finally block - it should probably be at the end of the try block.  Your current implementation will show the Success message when an exception is thrown - and the file might therefore be successful.

Comment: indeed  .. you are absolutely right .. it should edited and updated the way you said .. but the code was about a problem and its fixed :) no matter